# Visual Studio html helper not containing actionLink

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

A mate of mine has started a project in ASP.Net and wanted me to collaborate,
he sent me the files to open and so i did.

But I keep getting the following error: `'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic>' does not contain a definition for 'actionLink' and no extension method 'actionLink' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

After Googling I figured it might have something to do with web.conf...
I couldn't find anything faulty however, but just to be sure here's web.conf located in my views folder:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="projectWebKassa" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler" />
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**edit: added web helper to web.config**
Thanks in advance,
g3.

Comment: Have you installed all the necessary NuGet packages?

Comment: Which asp.net MVC version?

Comment: I like to believe so, yes

Comment: probably not exactly 5.0 but for some reason there is a character minimum

Comment: I think your friend has misspelled something.  It's ActionLink, not actionLink.  Search the code for actionLink (lowercase) and change it to uppercase.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works now (and i feel stupid for not seeing that myself hahahaha)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />  <---- THIS IS MISSING
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="projectWebKassa" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Comment: Added, it, rebuilded solution but still getting `'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic>' does not contain a definition for 'actionLink' and no extension method 'actionLink' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Could you add your list of System.Web assembly references?

Comment: After testing i'd like to add that it also works without `<add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />`